# Xcode : module name "" is not a valid identifier while running XC unit test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdwebimage

Trying to run XCTest with my CocoaPods set up using `SDWebImage`, and I can only see this error as below. Any suggestions?

> :0: error: module name "" is not a valid identifier
>   Command /Applications/Xcode8.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

But as soon as I edit the scheme and uncheck the test inside the builds, I am able to run the app on simulator but can't run the tests.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning build folder? under options

Comment: Did a clean build it wont work if the product module name is missing for test targets

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Always make sure all your test targets has the `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME` set to `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`

Comment: Can I add **PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME** to test target? I get There are already **PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME** so I am not able to add this to test target.

Comment: And ensure that PRODUCT_NAME does not include characters like a dash.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix the problem by following the steps below while migrating from Xcode 11 to 11.2:

1. Select the target
2. Go to Build Settings.
3. Then scroll down to Packaging
4. Product module name
5. If you have spaces in your module name, replace them with underscores

Comment: It should be noted that hyphens are invalid characters which should also be replaced with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your need to `$(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)` for `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME`.

`c99extidentifier` allows using dashes in the `PRODUCT_NAME`.

Also this is the default project value which can be inherited in each target.

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate the macos folder in your Flutter project.
2. Open the Runner.xcodeproj project file within the macos folder using Xcode.
3. In Xcode, select the "Runner" project in the project navigator on the left-hand side.
4. Go to the "Build Settings" tab for the "Runner" target.
5. Look for the setting named "Product Module Name" under the "Packaging" section. This setting determines the module name for your macOS app.
6. Verify that the module name is a valid identifier. It should consist of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and it must start with a letter.
7. If the module name is empty or invalid, provide a valid identifier. You can use the default value "Runner" or choose a different name that suits your project.
8. Once you've updated the module name, clean your project by selecting "Product" from the Xcode menu, then choose "Clean Build Folder".
9. Try building and running your macOS app again to see if the error has been resolved.