# Xcode 10 multiple commands build error for Pods dependency

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode10

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-cworwzaxajsmfkcfvourofovbggd/Build/Products/QA-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app':

1) Target 'MyProject' has create directory command with output '/Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-cworwzaxajsmfkcfvourofovbggd/Build/Products/QA-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app'

2) That command depends on command in Target 'MyProject': script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

It seems like a script in `Copy pods resources` is conflicting with the normal build command. I have tried all the available solutions

1. Removing redundant files from `copy bundle resources`.
2. Updating cocoapods.
3. Changing `product module` name under `Build settings` to
   a unique one.
4. Removed info.Plist from `Copy Bundle Resources`

**Temporary Fix**: Xcode > File > Workspace Settings > Build System > Choose "Legacy Build System"

Attaching my `Copy Pods Resources` screenshot
[image]

Comment: remove `info.plist` file from the Build Phases --> Copy Bundle Resources --> Info.plist
It will works for me

Comment: Please check your pod version using `pod --version`. For Xcode-10 after updating pod version to - `1.5.3` it's work for me

Comment: @NiravKotecha Tried it, but no luck.

Comment: have you found an answer to this except legacy build?

Comment: I tried many things but just these steps  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451421/2238515 solved for me

Answer (score 1):

@birdcage
- Update CocoaPods> Terminal

```
sudo gem update cocoapods
```

Then Delete **Pods** folder,**.xcworkspace** then delete **Podfile.lock**

then reinstall all library.

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing build systems to **`Legacy Build System`** works for me.

Xcode => File => Workspace Settings => Build System => Change to `"Legacy Build System"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try `sudo gem update cocoapods` and update your `cocoapods` version. that solved in my case.

Answer (score -4):

Just remove [CP] Copy Pods Resources from your project Target.