# Xcode 10.3 Multiple commands produce error

Tags: swift, xcode

After update from Xcode 10.2.1 to Xcode 10.3 I got those errors.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718018/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce/50719379#50719379) but can't figure out how to fix my errors because I don't have Info.plist in my Build Phase -> Copy Bundle Resources.

> Showing Recent Messages
>   Build system information
>   error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/creativeones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gcouriers-bqumzkqbwmahlygsipsuxneaxaxi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gcouriers.app/powered-by-google-on-white.png':
>   1) That command depends on command in Target 'gcouriers' (project 'gcouriers'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
>   2) That command depends on command in Target 'gcouriers' (project 'gcouriers'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
>
> Showing Recent Messages
>   Build system information
>   error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/creativeones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gcouriers-bqumzkqbwmahlygsipsuxneaxaxi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gcouriers.app/GooglePlaces.bundle':
>   1) That command depends on command in Target 'gcouriers' (project 'gcouriers'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
>   2) That command depends on command in Target 'gcouriers' (project 'gcouriers'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
>
> Showing Recent Messages
>   Build system information
>   error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/creativeones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gcouriers-bqumzkqbwmahlygsipsuxneaxaxi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gcouriers.app/GoogleMaps.bundle':
>   1) That command depends on command in Target 'gcouriers' (project 'gcouriers'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
>   2) That command depends on command in Target 'gcouriers' (project 'gcouriers'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
>
> Showing Recent Messages
>   Build system information
>   error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/creativeones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gcouriers-bqumzkqbwmahlygsipsuxneaxaxi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gcouriers.app/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle':
>   1) That command depends on command in Target 'gcouriers' (project 'gcouriers'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
>   2) That command depends on command in Target 'gcouriers' (project 'gcouriers'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
>
> Showing Recent Messages
>   :-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/creativeones/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gcouriers-bqumzkqbwmahlygsipsuxneaxaxi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/gcouriers.app/powered-by-google-on-white@2x.png':
>   1) That command depends on command in Target 'gcouriers' (project 'gcouriers'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
>   2) That command depends on command in Target 'gcouriers' (project 'gcouriers'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071090/multiple-commands-produced-error-xcode-10

Comment: Yes, running on Legacy Build System does the trick, but does this affects my build in any way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421408/xcode-10-multiple-commands-build-error-for-pods-dependency) worked for me!

Update CocoaPods> Terminal

```
sudo gem update cocoapods
```

Then Delete **Pods** folder,**.xcworkspace** then delete **Podfile.lock**

then reinstall all library.

```
pod install
```

And after those commands, I can build my project without using the legacy workaround.