# Xcode 10 - Multiple commands produce .app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

I have a project that I developed with Xcode 9, and after switching to Xcode 10 I get an error during build:

> error: Multiple commands produce 'SomePath/MyApp.app':
>   1) Target 'MyApp' has create directory command with output '/SomePath/Kvitt.app'
>   2) That command depends on command in Target 'MyApp': script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”

I had a similar issue with different project and `Info.plist` file, and I solved it using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719379/1921348)

However, this time the error refers to `MyApp.app`, and there is no such file in *Copy Bundle Resources*

Switching to *Legacy Build System* makes this go away, but want to know what's causing this and how to fix it in new build system

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev621201fb0

Comment: And watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/415/

Comment: Have you found any solution without switching the build system?

Comment: @AshleyMills Resource you linked describes situation where two targets produce `.app` file. In my case, the workspace contains only a single target, and the workspace itself is generated by Cocoapods. The error mentions a Cocoapods script build phase, so this rather sounds like a Cocoapods bug

Comment: I tried many things but just this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451421/2238515 solved for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 10 Error: Multiple commands produce for 'app' and 'appex'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382667/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce-for-app-and-appex)

Answer (score 3):

I have got the same issue : Build error in Xcode 10 "Multiple commands produce...

```
:-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/m/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FAR- 
axuthwysrkuqbcdvfglntqgbiugn/Build/Products/Debug- 
iphonesimulator/F.A.R.app/.gitkeep':
1) Target 'FAR' (project 'FAR') has copy command from '/Users/m/Desktop/Shubham 
 Code/Backup/Shubham 2018/SVN 
Codes/FAR/FAR/FAR/ThirdParty/BPStatusBarAlert/Assets/.gitkeep' to 
'/Users/m/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FAR- 
axuthwysrkuqbcdvfglntqgbiugn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F.A.R.app/.gitkeep'
2) Target 'FAR' (project 'FAR') has copy command from '/Users/m/Desktop/Shubham 
Code/Backup/Shubham 2018/SVN 
Codes/FAR/FAR/FAR/ThirdParty/BPStatusBarAlert/Classes/.gitkeep' to 
'/Users/m/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FAR- 
axuthwysrkuqbcdvfglntqgbiugn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/F.A.R.app/.gitkeep'
```

This can be resolved by following below steps :

Step 1 : Go to build Phases.

Step 2 : Copy bundle resources and remove the .gitkeep file.

Step 3 :Build and Success.

In your case some other file will create issue, So check the file name and delete it.

As per my investigation, issue is because of duplicacy of file.

Happy Coding.

Comment: I think you shouldn't have .gitkeep in bundle resources of your application

Comment: Thank you... sometimes I overlook the obvious while looking for a more complex reason.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue. If you are using Cocoapods, then you can solve the issue by upgrading to Cocoapods 1.5.3 from 1.4.0. as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382667/xcode-10-error-multiple-commands-produce-for-app-and-appex):

After that, just do `pod install` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by deintegrating cocoa pods and then installing it again.

I also cleared the derived data, then cleaned the code before running it again.

Comment: would be helpfull if you give the commands

Comment: First, cd to your project directory then,
pod deintgerate
pod install